# Google Android Maps Api v2 error

Tags: android-maps-v2

I have an error `com.example.mapdemo E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10` when I try to run a sample mpas application from ANDROID SDK.
How to resolve this error ?
I just want to see dialog with turn on location service. Such as standard google maps.
Thanx.